# Epsilon delta definition of limit gives seemingly nonsense result

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I want to calculate $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin\frac1x}{\sin\frac1x}$$
This obviously equals one, but the epsilon delta definition would then be:

For all $\epsilon$>0, there exists a $\delta$>0, such that
$$0<|x|<\delta \Rightarrow \Bigg|\frac{\sin\frac1x}{\sin\frac1x}-1\Bigg|<\epsilon$$
But $0<|x|<\delta$ also implies that there exists an x where $\big|\frac1x\big|$ is a multiple of pi, and $\frac{\sin\frac1x}{\sin\frac1x}=\frac00$, which is undefined. Assuming the limit equals one leads to a contradiction. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: $\frac{\sin\frac1x}{\sin\frac1x}=1$ is not a valid equality when $x=\frac  1 {n \pi}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that the (natural) domain of the function

$$f(x)=\frac{\sin(1/x)}{\sin(1/x)}$$

is $\operatorname{dom}(f) = \{x\in\mathbb{R} : x \neq 0 \text{ and } \sin(1/x) \neq 0\}$. So, the correct $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of that limit should be as follows:

> For any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
> $$ x \in \operatorname{dom}(f) \text{ and }0 < |x - 0| < \delta \quad \implies \quad |f(x) - 1| < \varepsilon. $$

Of course, this condition is obviously true since $f$ is identically $1$ on its domain.

Comment: Is the x∈dom(f) part implicit? I've never seen it

Comment: @RaunakChhatwal, I believe that this type of limit (where the function in the limit symbol is undefined at some points of every punctured neighborhood) is not covered in introductory calculus classes, and perhaps this is the reason you have never seen the condition $x \in \operatorname{dom}(f)$. However, that condition is necessary to state the definition of limit for more general class of functions.